# How to create new getter in the Magento grid

Tags: magento, getter

I have the following piece of code in my custom module grid.

```
     $this->addColumn('action',
     array(
            'header'    =>  Mage::helper('module')->__('Action'),
            'width'     => '100',
            'type'      => 'action',
            'getter'    => 'getId',     
            'actions'   => array(
                array(
                    'caption'   => Mage::helper('module')->__('Edit'),
                    'url'       => array('base'=> '*/*/edit'),
                    'field'     => 'id',                
                )
            ),
            'filter'    => false,
            'sortable'  => false,
            'index'     => 'stores',
            'is_system' => true,
    ));
```

I want to know that is there any way to make new getter in the grid. My purpose to do this is to pass the extra param in the url.

By using this, i am getting the following edit url

http://domain.com/index.php/module/adminhtml_module/edit/id/5/key/a19618bbaa3ee98ed395bc2fa552de35/

if will append the another getter to the url like 
'getter'    => 'getStoreId',

Than my url should be like:

http://domain.com/index.php/module/adminhtml_module/edit/id/5/store/5/key/a19618bbaa3ee98ed395bc2fa552de35/

Can anybody guide me that how can i do that.?

i tried to use the following code, but it did not work .

```
    $this->addColumn('action',
     array(
            'header'    =>  Mage::helper('module')->__('Action'),
            'width'     => '100',
            'type'      => 'action',
            'getter'    => array('getId','getStoreId'),     
            'actions'   => array(
                array(
                    'caption'   => Mage::helper('module')->__('Edit'),
                    'url'       => array('base'=> '*/*/edit'),
                    'field'     => array('id',store_id),                
                )
            ),
            'filter'    => false,
            'sortable'  => false,
            'index'     => 'stores',
            'is_system' => true,
    ));
```

Answer (score 2):

To add the store key to the url try changing the `actions` to

```
'actions'   => array(
    array(
        'caption' => Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Edit'),
        'url'     => array(
            'base'=>'*/*/edit',
            'params'=>array('store'=>$this->getRequest()->getParam('store'))
        ),
        'field'   => 'id'
    )
),
```

update `$this->getRequest()->getParam('store')` as needed

Reference /app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Catalog/Product/Grid.php

```
$this->addColumn('action',
    array(
        'header'    => Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Action'),
        'width'     => '50px',
        'type'      => 'action',
        'getter'     => 'getId',
        'actions'   => array(
            array(
                'caption' => Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Edit'),
                'url'     => array(
                    'base'=>'*/*/edit',
                    'params'=>array('store'=>$this->getRequest()->getParam('store'))
                ),
                'field'   => 'id'
            )
        ),
        'filter'    => false,
        'sortable'  => false,
        'index'     => 'stores',
));
```

Comment: It seems to be a cleaner approach rather than adding a new renderer class for a simple thing. Thank you and it should be marked as the first answer in my opinion.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to pass more than one value from grid, then you can use custom renderer:

```
    $this->addColumn('action',
     array(
        'header'    =>  Mage::helper('module')->__('Action'),
        'width'     => '100',
        'type'      => 'text',
        'filter'    => false,
        'sortable'  => false,
        'is_system' => true,
        'renderer'  => 'Company_MyModule_Block_Adminhtml_Renderer_Actionlink',
    ));
```

Renderer:

```
class Company_MyModule_Block_Adminhtml_Renderer_Actionlink extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid_Column_Renderer_Abstract {
  public function render(Varien_Object $row) {
    $url=$this->getUrl('*/*/edit', array('id'=>$row->getId(), 'storeId' => $row->getStoreId()));
    return sprintf("<a href='%s'>%s</a>", $url, Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Edit'));
  }
}
```